# Can we use 'NullCompactionStrategy'?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax, scylla

We know, we have a different type of compaction strategy in apache cassandra and ScyllaDB and their use cases. Can we use 'NullCompactionStrategy' ? if yes what is the impact on Scylla/Cassandra cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Using NullCompactionStrategy will effectively disable compaction on your table. This is fine for a short period if you are doing some data migration or you are going to write a huge amount of data in a short time but not recommended for a long time.

Cassandra writes are flushed to SSTables which are immutable. So every memory flush into the disk will create a new SSTable file. If you disable the compaction, the server will keep creating more and more files. So it is possible that if you update the value of a column it can be present in more than 1 file. Now your reads will have to go through many files to process a request.

The compaction process merges the SSTables together. If there was an update or a delete, the newest value for the field is kept by compaction and is written to the new SSTable, and the older versions are discarded. This means that the read will happen on a lesser number of files.

Disabling compaction will result in less CPU usage during writes but also means slow reads later. So either keep the compaction enabled or enable it once you are done with your migration.

Comment: Thanks. Is the only way to disable compaction in cassandra? Can we follow this process in our prod servers?

Comment: you should use nodetool disableautocompaction to disable compaction. https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsDisableAutoCompaction.html

Comment: Okay... but what about in scylla?

Comment: scyllaDB is basically a C++ implementation of Cassandra with better performance but fewer features. Compactions should work the same way in scyllaDB as they are in Cassandra.

Comment: @LetsNoSQL Scylla does not support `nodetool disableautocompaction` command, so the option is to use the `NullCompactionStrategy`.
Why would you want to disable compactions? that's Highly not recommended.

Comment: @TomerSan , Thanks I agree, but if require to disable compaction temporarily then what should I use?

Comment: @LetsNoSQL you will need to set that specific table to `NullCompactionStrategy` using `cqlsh` and once you want to enable it back, set your desired compaction strategy back again